# Can Kafka scale to tens of millions of topics?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm currently planning the development of a Device Server and am keen to use Kafka, however, I'm unsure if it's capable of supporting a paradigm where there is one topic per device, when there could be 10 million+ devices.

I would expect only one partition per topic and limited required storage (<1MB) per topic. If it makes any difference one topic with millions of partitions could also be considered.

Is anyone able to provide clarification of the scaling limits and expectations of Kafka at this level? In particular, I'm keen to understand the overheads per topic and the effectiveness/feasibility of an individual consumer consuming from ~10k subscribed topics over a single connection.

Any advice much appreciated,
Many thanks

Comment: Why a consumer needs to subscribe to ~10k topics? Devices are producers or consumers? Would help if you explain a little bit more about the overall architecture, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The consumers each hold stateful information of a set of ~10k devices, so a specific consumer must be subscribed to the topics/partitions representing the devices that it's effectively dealing with.

The consumers may need to transfer their stateful information to other consumers in order to load-balance and so the relationship between consumer and topic/partition is not fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka best practices would be to use keys rather than topics for that many devices. Kafka scales to an unlimited number of keys but not an unlimited number of topics

Comment: Thank you, my challenge is that I will have on the consumer side, many consumers each representing ~10k unique keys, which keys they represent could change as they load-balance.

I'm imagining there's a significant challenge in changing which partition this many keys goes to?

Comment: @AlistairLowe can you let kafka do the partitioning automatically using the normal Producer partitioner and consumer group feature? If you publish with keys, the default partitioner will ensure that all messages on the same key go to the same partition. That reduces the problem to one of assigning a balanced set of partitions per consumer which is what the normal consumer group features does. This scales really well and you can dynamically add new consumer instances and still have balanced consumption with guaranteed in order processing of any messages of the same key.

Answer (score 1):

Having one topic with many partitions has some advantages. First of all you can use keys, as already said, for specifying the device which is sending the message. You don't need to have the number of partitions equals to the number of devices but it could be less that that; thanks to the key usage, the main aspect is that messages from same device (same key) go always to the same partition and in order. On the consumer side you have the advantage to leverage on more consumers in the same consumer group working on different partitions and sharing the messages load; you can scale up to a number of consumers equals to the number of partitions.